# How to hide duplicated date value in certain column in r

Tags: r

I have dataframe example

```
user_id  create_date amount
   test   2018-08-12      1
          2018-08-12      5 
          2018-08-12      7
```

The 'user_id' column of this kind I got with the help of the command

```
example$user_id[duplicated(example$user_id)] <- ""
```

but it doesn't work with 'create_date' column

> "Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Is there anyway to cope with this?

Comment: Error in `[.default`(example$user_id, !duplicated(example$user_id),  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: `example$user_id[!duplicated(example$user_id)] ` Just realized it is a vector and not a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to coerce `""`to a date automatically and of course fails. You can

```
example$create_date <- as.character(example$create_date)
```

to change the column to character class and then use

```
example$create_date[duplicated(example$create_date)] <- ""
```

which should work. I wouldn't recommend it though as the column isn't in a proper date format afterwards. Probably it would be better to:

```
example$create_date[duplicated(example$create_date)] <- NA
```

If that makes sense for you.